# Choosing the correct Data Structure in Firebase Firestore for my Flutter Todo App

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently developing a ToDo app with Flutter and Firebase. The initial situation is as follows:

**1**. the user has to log in when he wants to create ToDos, i.e. the ToDos would have to be saved best under the UID, right?

**2**. a user can create multiple lists/categories, for this I also thought about the structure and came up with 2 ideas.

**First idea:**
I have 2 collections, one with the UserID and all todos and one with the UserID and all categories.

todo ->
title,
createdAt,
done,
category, (link to the second collection with the categories)
...

category ->
name,
icon,
...

**Second idea:**
I create a single collection per user, the first field is then an array with the name of the category, and in this array are all ToDos.

Unfortunately, I am a complete beginner in Firestore and therefore I am not sure if any of my suggestions would make sense. I hope that the initial situation is well described, otherwise you can still ask questions.

Thank you!

Edit: I just saw a video and I had another idea to create a collection with the UID. This contains all categories as documents and the categories have a subcollection with all Todos.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.